# Installed memcached via homebrew, how to start and stop server?

Tags: ruby, memcached, homebrew

I have memcached installed via homebrew.

1. how do I start/stop the server?
2. Any command-line tools to interact with memcached?
3. does homebrew have a way of removing a package?

Comment: maybe relevant for serverfault.com

Answer (score 43, accepted):

1. Brew *used to have* a command brew services (https://thoughtbot.com/blog/starting-and-stopping-background-services-with-homebrew), now deprecated. Instead, to get always-correct advice, run this command:

   ```
   brew info memcached
   ```
2. Via telnet: `telnet localhost 11211`

   See also [What are some useful tips/tools for monitoring/tuning memcached health?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110143/what-are-some-useful-tips-tools-for-monitoring-tuning-memcached-health)
3. `brew remove memcached`

Comment: "Warning: brew services is unsupported and will be removed soon. You should use launchctl instead." See answer from clee

Comment: I have extracted homebrew-services to its own repository, now that it is removed from the main homebrew repository  
https://github.com/gapple/homebrew-services

Comment: Please update the answer so it now begins with a warning about deprecated "brew services"

Answer (score 82):

When you installed it, it put a file named `homebrew.mxcl.memcached.plist` in `/usr/local/Cellar/memcached/$version/`; you copy that file into `~/Library/LaunchAgents` and then tell launchd to start it with `launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.memcached.plist`.

If you were watching the console carefully during the `brew install` command, it should have said something about doing these exact steps. If you run `brew info` it'll re-print this information, e.g. `brew info memcached`.

You should probably read https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage -- it has more useful documentation including the `brew remove` command which will remove the package if you decide you don't want it.

Comment: thanks, I noticed it outputs the instructions for newer installs, but don't recall if it did it with memcached as I installed it a long time back.

Comment: Sure, but how do you *stop* the service?

Comment: `launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.danga.memcached.plist` of course. :)

Comment: At some point the filename changed to  `~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.memcached.plist`

Answer (score 41):

Additionally you can run "brew info", if you have forgotten about the instructions.

```
→ brew info memcached
memcached 1.4.7
http://memcached.org/
Depends on: libevent
/usr/local/Cellar/memcached/1.4.6 (8 files, 156K)

You can enable memcached to automatically load on login with:
mkdir -p ~/Library/LaunchAgents
cp /usr/local/Cellar/memcached/1.4.7/com.danga.memcached.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents/
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.danga.memcached.plist

Or start it manually:
    /usr/local/bin/memcached

Add "-d" to start it as a daemon.

http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/commits/master/Library/Formula/memcached.rb
```

Comment: Copying the plist file to my ~/Library/LaunchAgents/ folder hasn't seemed to make it start automatically on boot for me. :-(

Answer (score 22):

To restart:
If you have the memcached starting up with launchd and your plist file has

```
  <key>KeepAlive</key>
  <true/>
```

Then you can just kill the process and it will reboot automagically.

```
ps ux | grep memcached
pkill -f memcached
ps ux | grep memcached
```

To stop launchd from restarting automatically:

```
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.memcached.plist
```

To add memcached to launchd again:

```
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.memcached.plist
```

To uninstall something installed by homebrew:

```
brew uninstall memcached
```

Answer (score 16):

And you can also create aliases

```
alias memcached-start="launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.memcached.plist"
alias memcached-stop="launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.memcached.plist"
alias memcached-restart="launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.memcached.plist;launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.memcached.plist"
```

and after that you cant easy start/stop/restart memcached

```
memcached-start
memcached-stop
memcached-restart
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use [Lunchy](https://github.com/mperham/lunchy) to set the start/stop. Lunchy is a wrapper written over `launchctl`. I’ve written a detailed [post](http://www.rahuljiresal.com/2014/03/installing-memcached-on-mac-with-homebrew-and-lunchy/) about this.

```
$ gem install lunchy
$ mkdir ~/Library/LaunchAgents
$ cp /usr/local/Cellar/memcached/$version/homebrew.mxcl.memcached.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents/
```

To start memcached

```
$ lunchy start memcached
```

To stop memcahed

```
$ lunchy stop memcached
```

Answer (score 4):

You can enable Memcached to automatically load on login.

This first line creates a symlink (symbolic link) from where Homebrew installed it to the LaunchAgents folder.

```
ln -sfv /usr/local/Cellar/memcached/1.4.17/homebrew.mxcl.memcached.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents/
```

Then to launch it now:

```
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.memcached.plist
```