# gem install memcached is failed on Lion

Tags: rubygems, memcached, osx-lion, libmemcache

I want to use memcached gem (http://fauna.github.com/fauna/memcached/) on Mac OS X Lion (10.7.2).
The Xcode 4.2 was installed already.

I have installed memcached, and libmemcached by Homebrew.

```
$ brew list -v 
libmemcached 0.50
memcached 1.4.10
```

And I use ruby 1.9.3-p0 with rvm (ruby version manager).

```
$ ruby -v 
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]
$ rvm -v
rvm 1.9.2 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]
```

But I cann't install memcached gem (1.3.5). I pasted installation log following gits.
    https://gist.github.com/1395459

Some errors happend in the make of libmemcached. I saw directories of that.

```
$ pwd 
/Users/inohiro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/memcached-1.3.5/ext/libmemcached-0.32
```

The configure is succeed. But make (all) is failed.

```
$ make all
make  all-recursive
Making all in docs
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in libmemcached
make  all-am
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
Making all in libmemcachedutil
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in support
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in clients
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -std=gnu99 -O3  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wundef -Wshadow  -fdiagnostics-show-option -fvisibility=hidden -Wformat=2  -Wstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wmissing-declarations -Wcast-align -Wswitch-default -Wswitch-enum -Wwrite-strings    -D_THREAD_SAFE   -rpath /usr/local/lib/libmemcached -lsasl2 -L/usr/local/lib -o memcat memcat.o libutilities.la ../libmemcached/libmemcached.la 
libtool: link: gcc -std=gnu99 -O3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wundef -Wshadow -fdiagnostics-show-option -fvisibility=hidden -Wformat=2 -Wstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wmissing-declarations -Wcast-align -Wswitch-default -Wswitch-enum -Wwrite-strings -D_THREAD_SAFE -o .libs/memcat memcat.o  -L/usr/local/lib ./.libs/libutilities.a ../libmemcached/.libs/libmemcached.dylib -lsasl2
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_memcached_create", referenced from:
      _main in memcat.o
  "_memcached_behavior_set", referenced from:
      _main in memcat.o
      _process_hash_option in libutilities.a(utilities.o)
  "_memcached_get", referenced from:
      _main in memcat.o
  "_memcached_free", referenced from:
      _main in memcat.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [memcat] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Full log of configure and make of libmemcached is here.
    https://gist.github.com/1395470

Please tell me How to install memcached gem to Lion :/

**Postscript-1**

I tried "brew link memcached". But return a error. What should I do?

```
$ brew link memcached 
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/memcached/1.4.10... 
Error: Cannot link memcached
Another version is already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/memcached/1.4.10
```

**Postscript-2**

I tried remove /usr/local/Cellar/memcached/. And run 'brew link memcached', but get following error.

```
$ rm -rf memcached
$ brew link memcached 
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/memcached
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this:

```
ls -l /usr/local/include/memcached
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  staff  43 Jul 18 14:17 /usr/local/include/memcached -> ../Cellar/memcached/1.4.5/include/memcached
```

you need to remove that old link first:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/include/memcached
```

then try the `brew link memcached` again

You probably also want to do this:

[Installed memcached via homebrew, how to start and stop server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247645/installed-memcached-via-homebrew-how-to-start-and-stop-server)

Comment: Thank you for your kindly. But I couldn't solve. Add Postscript-2.

Comment: Is "sudo rm /usr/local/include/memcaced (<-It's symbolic link" correct? Or "sudo rm /usr/local/Cellar/memcaced/ (<-It's directory"?

Comment: sorry, that was a typo. Try this: `sudo rm /usr/local/include/memcached`

Comment: you need to  remove the symbolic link /usr/local/include/memcached as well!

Comment: Yes. I removed symbolic link (/usr/local/include/memcached/). But error (Postscript-1) was shown still.

Comment: Thank you. At last I have succeeded. memcached.gem was updated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is gcc cannot find memcached library installed by brew.

Try to run `brew link memcached`, then run `gem install memcached` again.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I add a postscript about this.